# Reading property values to boolean in Kotlin/Spring with @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-expression-language

I've seen examples of how to do this in Java but I'm lacking an example in Kotlin. I want to read a property into a boolean using the `@Value` annotation from Spring

In my constructor I'm doing:

```kotlin
@Value("\${kafka.userComplexTopics:false}")
val useComplexTopicsString: String,
```

to pull out my String value and then in my class I have:

```kotlin
private val useComplexTopics = useComplexTopicsString.toBoolean()
```

I've been screwing around with SePL and can't make it work in one line.

Answer (score 3):

Spring should do this conversion for you. Unless you need the Stringified version, try setting your type to a Boolean.

```
@Component
class SomeClass(
    @Value("\${kafka.useComplexTopics:false}") val useComplexTopics: Boolean
) {
    init {
        println("UseComplexTopics: $useComplexTopics")
    }
}
```